# How to generate a series （1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4）

Tags: r, series

I am confused that how to generate a series （like this `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4`） in R.
I use the `for loop`  and `rep` function like this,

```
for (i in 1:10)
{rep(i,i)}
```

but I can't paste them together.

Comment: @Julius thx!  what about 1,-2,-2,3,3,3,-4,-4,-4,-4,5,5,5,5,5 ?

Comment: thank u.  it is so simple,just apply the multiplication. i think i must study much harder.

Answer (score 8):

```
rep(1:4, 1:4)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Similarly for another series we get

```
rep(1:5, 1:5) * (-1)^rep(0:4, 1:5)
[1]  1 -2 -2  3  3  3 -4 -4 -4 -4  5  5  5  5  5
```

Comment: For extra credit :-), write the code for the infamous sequence `1 , 1 1, 2 1, 1 1 1 2, 3 1 1 2,...`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, nice one, `cw<-function(x,n)if(n>0){print(x);o<-rle(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]);cw(paste0(o$l,o$v,collapse=""),n-1)}` and try `cw("1",10)`

Comment: Cool solution!  I wrote one a while back that used this method instead:  `morrisseq<-function(seqlen) {`
`theseq<- list(1)`
`for( j in 2:seqlen) {`
`thetab<-table(theseq[[j-1]])`
`# it's more pleasing if replace 'unlist' with 'as.vector' `
`theseq[[j]]<-as.vector( sapply( 1:length(thetab), function(k)` `c(thetab[k], as.numeric(names(thetab)[k])) ))`
`}`
`return(theseq)`
`}`